# Зачем нужны [преобразование] и [конвертация]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки, замена-меток

Всё программирование связано с преобразованиями, которые также можно назвать в некоторой степени конвертациями. Эта метки по этой причине зараннее обречены, так как преобразованиями (так и конвертациями) можно назвать множество вещей.

Если посмотреть как они используются ([преобразование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [конвертация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)), то чаще всего речь идет идёт о преобразовании типов (метка [преобразование-типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2)). Намного реже речь идёт о чём-то другом, но и для этих случаев есть другие более конкретные метки.

Ввиду данной расплывчатости меток, вижу смысл заменить на [преобразование-типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2) или более уместную метку (если есть), таким образом они удалятся. Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: А что с [такими](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784472/15479) вопросами?

Comment: @Suvitruf Там уже висит тег [tag:видео], который у нас используют для обработки видео, поэтому для данного вопроса удаление метки не ухудшит его поиск.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вы считаете, что любая обработка видео - это конвертация? Если нет - то почему наличие более общего тега должно, по вашему, приводить к удалению более специфических?

Comment: @PashaPash Метка должна быть недвусмысленной, это не общие метки, эти метки которые способствуют хаосу, так как не имеют чёткой сферы ответственности. Для конвертации видео нужна отдельная метка, если считаете эту сферу заслуживающей своей метки.

Comment: Вспоминая *проверку* - может ли такая метка быть единственной на вопросе? Есть ли у нас специалисты по преобразованию и конвертации?